# How do I set the ClientWebSocketOptions on a ClientWebSocket in the System.Net.WebSockets

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket

I want to specify an *ssl certificate* for a web *socket client* to use when connecting to a *web socket server*.

The only [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) for a `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` has 0 parameters. I would expect there to be an override with (Options) as a parameter but there is not.

The [ConnectAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.connectasync?view=netcore-3.1) method has 2 parameters: `Uri` and `CancellationToken`.  I would expect there to be an override with `(Uri, CancellationToken, Options)` but there is not.

The `ClientWebSocket` [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.options?view=netcore-3.1) property is get but not set, so i cannot call

```
ws.options = MyClientWebSocketOptions
```

There is no `SetOptions` method on the `ClientWebSocket` class.

The [ClientWebSocketOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocketoptions?view=netcore-3.1) class has a [ClientCertificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocketoptions.clientcertificates?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_WebSockets_ClientWebSocketOptions_ClientCertificates) property that is is set-able, so I have assumed this is the way to specify the *certificate*.

I can create a `ClientWebSocketOptions` with the correct *certificate*, but i need to know how to make a `ClientWebSocket` use those options.

Comment: +1 because its rare to see paragraphs, a well formatted post, links to the relevant information and well thought out / structured question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can't do this: `ws.options = MyClientWebSocketOptions`, but you can do this:

```
var webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
webSocket.Options.ClientCertificates.Add(new 
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate());
```

It may be a getter, but that's fine as you can just modify the `ClientWebSocketOptions` the getter returns that the implementation instantiates for you.

Once you call `ConnectAsync`, that `Options` property becomes "read only" and you can no longer modify it (from what I remember)

Comment: Ah ha! I see! I will give this a try! Thanks. Will accept your answer if it works.